# Accessing Structs and Calloc

Tags: c, caching, struct, segmentation-fault

I am trying to simulate a simple cache. I am having a couple problems. 1) Is is possible to make the array length in Line or Set arbitrary. Like through the use of a constructor. 2) I get a Seg Fault when I run this code and I can't tell why. I am accessing the arrays incorrectly?

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Line {
    unsigned int valid;
    unsigned int tag;
}line;

typedef struct Line Line;

struct Set {
    Line lines[5];
}set;

typedef struct Set Set;

struct Cache {
    Set sets[5];
}cache;

typedef struct Cache Cache;

int main(void) {
  Cache *cache = calloc(1,sizeof(Cache));
  
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(int j=0; i<5; j++){
            cache->sets[i].lines[j].valid = 0;
            cache->sets[i].lines[j].tag = 0;
        }
    }

  free(cache);
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your inner loop: `for (int j = 0; i < 5; j++) {` should be `for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {`.

Comment: OT: You are declaring global variables called `line`, `set`, and `cache`. I'm guessing that you don't want those. For example, the declaration for `struct Cache` should be `struct Cache { Set sets[5]; };` Note that the final `cache` is removed.

Comment: Of course, after `calloc`, looping over the new object to set it to 0 is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

There are two idiomatic ways to make variable length structures.   The first is:

```
struct blah {
    int a, b, c;
    char d, e, f;
    short g;
    MyType x[0];
};
```

To create such a structure, you would:

```
struct blah *MakeBlah(int n) {
     struct blah *p;
     if ((p = malloc(sizeof *p + sizeof *p->x * n)) != 0) {
          /* whatever */
     }
     return p;
}
```

The other is:

```
struct blah {
    int a, b, c;
    char d, e, f;
    short g;
    MyType *x;
};

struct blah *MakeBlah(int n) {
    struct blah *p;
    if ((p = malloc(sizeof *p + sizeof *p->x * n)) != 0) {
         p->x = (MyType *)(p+1);
    }
    return p;
}
```

In both cases, after `MakeBlah` you can freely fill up x[0..n-1] to your hearts desire.

The first approach is a bit tidier, and can survive `realloc()` without interventions, whereas the second approach needs to reset `x` in the case of a realloc.

The second approach is compatible with all versions of *C*, from *real C* right through to the latest secretion of *the standard*; whereas the first approach is only valid in some discharges of *the standard*, and may yet be withdrawn by a later exudation from the *standards body*.

Comment: It depends upon the C standard. Read about [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)s - a third, more modern way. For the first case `x[0]` becomes `x[]`